# How to Convert Date and find the difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure since when how many days since the customer last Ordered, by using  their most recent order date and converting it to days.

So far I have this, but I don't know how to get it to change to days. I don't think I am on the right track.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEnK0.png)

```
  Count(*),
   GetDate(), Max as SinceLastOrder
FROM    
ORDERS
Group BY CustomerID
Having Max(OrderDate)
```

Comment: please mention DB name as well. In  most of the database, you will get `datediff` type function. In oracle its `sysdate-LastOrderDate` should give you `days since last order` value

Comment: Please include the sample data as a table inside your question, not as an image (otherwise people must copy character by character the samples to reproduce your issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all determine whats max order date.

```
select CustomerID, Max(OrderDate) mxorddt from ORDERS group by CustomerID
```

Then calculate date difference from today and calculate SinceLastOrder.

```
select 
mxorder.CustomerID ,
datediff(day, GETDATE(),mxorddt  ) DaysSinceLastOrder
from  
(select CustomerID, Max(OrderDate) mxorddt 
  from ORDERS 
 group by CustomerID) mxorder
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `datediff()`:

```
select o.customerID,
       datediff(day, max(o.orderdate), getdate())
from orders o
group by o.customerID;
```